# Updating web page caching when update my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create cache file for my webpage with php .But I want to change automatically when updating my webpage.How to solve these case.
Please say me these solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution to this is to create a manifest file and include the resources you wish to cache in there. When you need to make a change, just alter the manifest and call

```
var appCache = window.applicationCache;

appCache.update(); // Attempt to update the user's cache.

...

if (appCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
  appCache.swapCache();  // The fetch was successful, swap in the new cache.
}
```

code and more info from: [htmlrocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)